# How to check keyboard state while painting on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I'm just mucking around a bit with HTML5 canvas and painting. I happened to find [this article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/) by Opera that describes well how to set up a simple application.

I would like to extend it so that the user may set up a vanishing point (1 point perspective) that may be used to constrain painting. To allow this I need to figure out a way to define some modifier keys to limit the result (i.e. constraints map as (key=>axis) a=>x, s=>y, d=>z).

Is there some way to check out which key the user has pressed while handling the "mousedown" event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it only will work when the document have focus.

You should add a listener to the body attending for the key press event, when it has triggered, you store it in a variable emptying it afterwards when user triggers key release, an example should be like this :

```
document.body.onkeydown=function(evt){evt=evt?evt:window.event;console.log(evt)};
document.body.onkeyup=function(evt){evt=evt?evt:window.event;console.log(evt)};
```

then you only should identify evt.keyCode and act with it.

You could try third party libraries like [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js) too.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me to the right direction.

I ended up using "window.onkeydown" and "window.onkeyup" handlers. I'm not sure if that's the optimal solution but that appears to work just fine in this case.

shortcut.js looks somewhat interesting too. I gave it a go initially. The problem was that it did not support release event. Otherwise it looks like a cool library.